# Facebook Graph API 2.0/2.1 missing features

Tags: facebook, api, facebook-graph-api, search, feed

Now that Facebook's Graph API v1.0 is soon to be obsolete, several features that exist in the old version will not be available in the newer versions (v2.x), such as post search and most importantly - News Feed search.

Is Facebook planning to drop complete support for these features without providing some sort of alternative?
What I am asking is whether there will be any way to search through News Feeds and/or posts in the upcoming Graph API versions?

Thanks.

Comment: If we removed the feature I would interpret that as we are dropping support for that feature. We didn't remove it just to add it back later

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Facebook has depreciated a number of APIs, including search for Posts on Facebook. And while these endpoints will continue to work with v1.0, the are no longer supported in v2.0 and v2.1. There is no point is adding support for APIs that are being removed.

The reason for Facebook dropping searching for Posts is unknown, but it looks unlikely that an alternative API will be created for this.

One of the reasons for depreciating some of the APIs is that only a very small number of developers make use of them, so it's not worth Facebook's time to keep on maintaining these. Another is that some APIs are abused by developers, spoiling the experience for users, and so everyone suffers by the removal of these.